# How to send array to struts action class via ajax

Tags: jquery, ajax, struts2

I have problem to send dynamic data which is iterated by struts iterator as an array to struts action class as individual array via ajax call and how to receive in struts action class

Here is my sample code:

**struts iterations**

```
<table width="100%" class="table table-striped table-bordered table-hover" id="dataTables-example3">
    <thead>
    <tr>
    <th><a href="#" id="selectall">Select all</a></th>
    <th>Student Name</th>
    <th>Phone</th>
    <th>Email</th>
    <th>ReferenceId</th>
    </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
    <s:iterator value="adminSms">
    <tr>
    <td><s:checkbox name="refIDS" cssClass="case" fieldValue="%{ref}" /></td>
    <td><s:property value="studentname" /></td>
    <td id="phone"><s:property value="phone" /></td>
    <td id="email"><s:property value="email" /></td>
    <td><s:property value="ref" /></td>
    </tr>
    </s:iterator>
    </tbody>
    </table>
```

**Ajax call**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
            $('Send').click(function() {
                var Data = {
                    phone : $('#phone').val(),
                    email : $('#email').val()
                }
                $.ajax({
                    type : 'POST',
                    url : 'myURL',
                    data : JSON.stringify(Data)
                });
            });
        });
```

**Action class**

```
public class MyActionClass extends ActionSupport {

    private String [] phoneNumbers;
    private String [] emails;

    public String[] getPhoneNumbers() {
        return phoneNumbers;
    }

    public void setPhoneNumbers(String[] phoneNumbers) {
        this.phoneNumbers = phoneNumbers;
    }

    public String[] getEmails() {
        return emails;
    }

    public void setEmails(String[] emails) {
        this.emails = emails;
    }

    @Override
    public String execute() throws Exception {
        for (int i = 0; i < emails.length; i++) {
            System.out.println(emails[i]);
        }
        for (int i = 0; i < phoneNumbers.length; i++) {
            System.out.println(phoneNumbers[i]);
        }
        return SUCCESS;
    }
}
```

Comment: You can send it via Ajax.

Comment: Send just id and retrieve object in action.

Comment: What is `Send` in `$('Send')`? What do you trying to achieve? Why not to send only id?

Comment: when i click submit  i need to send phone and email data into struts action class

Comment: Do you need ajax? Why not simple form or link with parameters? Why not to send just id?

Comment: How tell me i need to send two fields. format is there send single value using fieldValueAttribute={%name}

Comment: @RomanC can i send row by row into struts action class

Comment: @RomanC can you say comments about my answer

Answer (score -1):

Here in the below code to send two field values i concatenate two field values in fieldValue attribute

```
<s:iterator value="adminSms">
<tr>
<td><s:checkbox name="emails" cssClass="case" fieldValue="%{phone+'@'+email}" /></td>
<td><s:property value="studentname" /></td>
<td id="phone"><s:property value="phone" /></td>
<td id="email"><s:property value="email" /></td>
<td><s:property value="ref" /></td>
</tr>
</s:iterator>
```

Comment: It's wrong. It doesn't map struts properties.

Comment: @RomanC am getting both email and phone data in between @ symbol. when it comes to action i used split function to make separate arrays

Comment: it is just expression, mapping data should be bi-directional.